# How To Use Blazor Syncfusion SfGrid with nested object

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor, blazor, syncfusion

I am using a Syncfusion Grid to display a list of `ChildRecord` objects. The `ChildRecord` class contains a `Name` class. The `Name` class contains the child's first name and last name as strings. For some reason, the grid is displaying the variables inside the `Name` object as blank. I have attached the relevant code.

```
<SfGrid DataSource="@ChildRecords" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" AllowFiltering="true" AllowGrouping="true">
<GridPageSettings PageSize="5"></GridPageSettings>
<GridColumns>
    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(ChildRecord.Name.FirstName) HeaderText="First Name" Width="150"></GridColumn>
    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(ChildRecord.Name.LastName) HeaderText="Last Name" Width="150"></GridColumn>
    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(ChildRecord.ID) HeaderText="ID" Width="150"></GridColumn>
    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(ChildRecord.DoB) HeaderText="DoB" Width="150"></GridColumn>
</GridColumns>
```

Here is how the table renders in the Blazor app:
[image]

I hypothesize that SfGrid is internally implemented in a way that does not support nested objects. I would like to know if there is a workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to display a nested property (complex data) value in the Grid. You can achieve complex data binding in the `DataGrid` by using the dot (`.`) operator in the `column.field`. In the following examples, `Name.FirstName` and `Name.LastName` are complex data.

Reference:

https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/datagrid/columns#complex-data-binding

```xml
<SfGrid DataSource="@Employees" Height="315"> 
    <GridColumns> 
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(EmployeeData.EmployeeID) HeaderText="EmployeeID" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="120"></GridColumn> 
        <GridColumn Field="Name.FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" Width="150"></GridColumn> 
        <GridColumn Field="Name.LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" Width="130"></GridColumn> 
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(EmployeeData.Title) HeaderText="Title" Format="C2" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="120"></GridColumn> 
    </GridColumns> 
</SfGrid>
```

```cs
@code{ 
  ... 

  public class EmployeeData 
  { 
    public int? EmployeeID { get; set; } 
    public EmployeeName Name { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
  }  

  public class EmployeeName 
  { 
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work on custom struct. only class/record